# I am getting Cannot find an SPSite that contains the following…Error

Tags: powershell, url, sharepoint-2010

I have a PowerShell script below that outputs a list of items and files from a site:

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
 function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
    $web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
      if ($excludeLists -notcontains $list.Title) {
        foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
          foreach($version in $item.Versions){
            $personField = $item.Fields.GetField("Author");
            $authorObject = $personField.GetFieldValue($item["Author"]);
            $authorName = $authorObject.LookupValue;
            $userField = $version.Fields.GetField("Editor");
            $editorObject = $userField.GetFieldValue($version["Editor"]);
            $editorName = $editorObject.LookupValue;
            $localOffset = +5;
            $modified = $version["Modified"] -as [datetime];
            if ($modified.IsDaylightSavingTime()) { $localOffset += 1 }
            $modifiedLocal = $modified.addHours(-$localOffset);
            $data = @{
              "Version" = $version.VersionLabel
              "List Name" = $list.Title
              "Created By" = $authorName
              "Created Date" = $item["Created"]
              "Modified By" = $editorName
              "Modified Date" = ($modifiedLocal -as [datetime]).DateTime
              "Item Name" = $item.Name
            }
          New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"
        }
      }

      $web.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
Get-DocInventory | Expport-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\TestOutput.csv
```

My problem is that when I run the script I get an error:

```
"Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url: http://contoso.com/sites/Test10".
```

It doesn't make sense because when I use a different Url like `http://contoso/sites/Departments/FRP` the script works.

I have tried these variations:

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"
$web = Get-SPSite "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Test10"
```

But I still get the same error mentioned previously. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the script? If `http://contoso.com/sites/Test10` was considered an `SPSite` wouldn't it work if I used the second variation?

Comment: Even if it were a site collection, the get-spweb cmdlet would work to grab the root site of the collection. You're sure /sites/test10 is a site and not a managed path? And you're running this script from a SharePoint web front end server?

Comment: Just a question. If the Url, in this case http://contoso.com/sites/Test10, is not available in the list of Web Applications (ie Central Admin>Manage Web Applications), then the script would return Cannot find SPSite .... because obviously the Url does not exist in the environment I'm running the script in right? Just to clarify the Url http://contoso.com/sites/Test10 is available but in a different environment just not the one I was running the script on. Could you please clarify if I'm on track?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track. If you've checked through each of the web applications listed in central admin and not found `/sites/Test10` as a site collection within any of the web applications, then the site does not exist in the current SharePoint farm.

Comment: Thriggle thanks for the answer. I have asked everywhere as layman's as I can but still got the run around. Again, thanks for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues you can check:

1. The username you are using has administrative rights on the SQL
   server.
2. You have run the windows power shell ISE as an administrator.
3. You are running the script from the application server where share
   point is installed.